# assign a string type golang

Tags: go, types

I'm having a hard time assigned a string to a type string. So I have this type:

```
type Username string
```

I then have a function that returns a string

What I'm trying to do is set username to that returned string:

```
u := &Username{returnedString}
```

I also tried

```
var u Username
u = returnedString
```

But I always get an error.

Comment: Username is a string, not a struct, so you can't do u :=&Username{returnedString}. Is there a reason you can't do var u string?

Comment: Can you give more detail about the error?

Comment: @william.taylor.09 Username is not a string but a custom type built on a underlying type string.

Answer (score 20):

As others have pointed out, you'll need to do an explicit type conversion:

```
someString := funcThatReturnsString()
u := Username(someString)
```

I'd recommend reading [this article](http://dominik.honnef.co/posts/2012/12/go__on_implicit_type_conversions__type_identity_and_a_little_gotcha/) on implicit type conversion. Specifically, Honnef references Go's specifications on [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability):

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") in any of these cases:
>
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a named type.

So in your example, the `returnedString` is already a "named type": it has type `string.` If you had instead done something like

```
var u Username
u = "some string"
```

you would have been ok, as the `"some string"` would be implicitly converted into type `Username` and both `string` and `Username` have the underlying type of `string`.

Answer (score 13):

You've made a user-defined type "Username". You cannot assign a value of one type to another type (in this case a string to Username) without converting. Incidentally you can assign a string literal to it.

```
var u Username
u = "test"
```

Will work.

```
var u Username
    var s string

    s = "test"
    u = s
```

Will give you the error:

> cannot use s (type string) as type Username in assignment

You can *convert* from one type to another, so...:

```
var u Username
    var s string
    s = "test"
    u = Username(s)
```

...will also work. "u" will be of type Username with the value "test".

For the record these are not meant as idiomatic examples. I am simply trying to clearly illustrate what's going on with the types here.

Answer (score 1):

Type casting in go is explained [in the tutorial "A Tour of Go"](https://tour.golang.org/basics/13)

See [here for an example](https://play.golang.org/p/GFj3im1UFD) using your types.